# Floating sidebar next to <% yield %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, partial, yield

I'm trying to float a sidebar nav as a partial in my rails app. Here is the relevant part of my application layout:

```
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
      <% end %>
  <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>

</body>
```

I'm using Twitter bootstrap in this app, fyi. I expected this to render above <% yield %>, but I can't figure out how to render the sidebar floating next to yield. How can I do this? I have not applied any custom css to the sidebar yet. I have applied class of "sidebar-nav-fixed" to the div containing the sidebar content. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem.  May be something like this would work:

```
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
      <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
      <% end %>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span4"><%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %></div>
          <div class="span8"><%= yield %></div>
      </div>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something different from the bootstrap documentation link you provided. It's in my answer below. It seems I have a lot to learn about bootstrap. Thanks again!

Comment: Very nice!  Yes you had to choose your classes according to your requirement, what I presented was just an example of how you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From some direction by vinodadhikary, here is what worked:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```